# Disable autoloader from trying to load JsonSerializable

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have the following setup in a library within CodeIgniter:

```
class DataModelAutoloader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
        log_message('debug', 'QR-Invited autoloader initialized');
    }

    public function loader($className)
    {
        log_message("debug", "Accessing loader for class: " . $className);
        if (substr($className, 0, 9) == 'datamodel') {
            $fullyQualifiedPath = APPPATH.str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className).'.php';
            log_message('debug', 'Fully qualified path is: ' . $fullyQualifiedPath);
            require APPPATH.str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className).'.php';
        }
    }
}
```

Now, one of my data models, `Invite`, in `datamodel/Invite.php` is getting loaded, but it's defined as:

```
class Invite implements JsonSerializable {
  ...
};
```

The problem is that it is now trying to load `datamodel/JsonSerializable.php`, which, of course, doesn't exist, because I want to use the built-in PHP 5.4.0 `JsonSerializable`. (I have PHP 5.5.X installed on the box I'm running on). So, I'm getting the following exception when I run this code:

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  require(qrinvited-application/datamodel/JsonSerializable.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Datamodelautoloader.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 20</p>
```

Is there a way to disable attempted autoloading for things like this that should be built-in to PHP5? Or, perhaps I'm doing something wrong in how I'm extending the class?

Comment: if its all about namespaces use implements \JsonSerializable

Comment: Yep, that was it, @s.d.a.p.e. Can you post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its all about 'namespaces' use `implements \JsonSerializable`. The `\` makes it so that PHP knows to use the `default` namespace instead of the namespace the class currently resides within (in this case, `datamodel`).